# Partitioned cookie (CHIPS) in iframe not being sent as expected

Tags: html, google-chrome, setcookie, chips

I have a top level site1.com that has a child iframe with src pointing to bot.com.

bot.com just contains a simple js script that does a fetch to auth.com/login which returns it a cookie with these params:

Domain=auth.com, SameSite=None, Path=/, Secure, HttpOnly & Expires in 1 hr

Then it does another fetch to auth.com/auth, but the cookie is not sent as expected.

Looking at the cookie in Chrome (latest ver) debugger I see it is partitioned to the top level site1.com.  Research showed it's related to CHIPS - but my second call is from the same iframe, nested in the same parent page... why would it not send the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually a silly solution where the initial fetch [to url that was setting the cookie] also needed to have `credentials: include` (I was already doing this on second fetch).
The initial [Mozilla Fetch API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) I was referring to had no mention of it affecting accepting a cookie, but later I found it mentions it applies to send & receive [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials).